# Use awk to separate text file into multiple files

Tags: shell, awk

I've read a couple of other questions about this, but none of them seem to be working. I'm currently trying to split something like file A.txt using the delimiter "STOPHERE".

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN{
    RS = "STOPHERE"
    file = 0}
{
    file++
    print $0 > ("sepf" file)
}' A.txt
```

File A:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      lwdjnuqqfqaaaaaaaaaa   qlknfqek fkgnl       efekfnwegelflfne
ldnwefne f STOPHEREsdfnkjnf nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnasd  fefffffffffffffflllo  

aldn3orn    STOPHERE

fknjke bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbowqff STOPHERE i
asfjfenf STOPHERE
```

Into these:

sepf1:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      lwdjnuqqfqaaaaaaaaaa   qlknfqek fkgnl       efekfnwegelflfne
ldnwefne f
```

sepf2:

```
sdfnkjnf nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnasd  fefffffffffffffflllo  

aldn3orn
```

sepf3:

```
    #line starts here
fknjke bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbowqff
```

sepf4:

```
 i
asfjfenf
```

So basically, the formatting has to stay exactly the same between the STOPHERE.

But for some reason, this is the kind of output I'm getting in some of the files:

Eg: sepf2

```
TOPHEREsdfnkjnf nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnasd  fefffffffffffffflllo  

aldn3orn
```

Any ideas as to why the "TOPHERE" remains??

Comment: This says only the first char is used as the record separator http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_19.html

Comment: Is there any way I can change this so that it uses the whole word?

Comment: Try nawk or gawk depending on your OS.  They allow a regex.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk allows RS to be a regex. So you can provide multiple characters as a record separator. Your code can also be simplified as AWK provides a default value of 0.
So this will generate separate files for each record.

```
awk -v RS="STOPHERE" '{print $0 > ("sepf" ++file)}'
```